# Pointers truncated in ROOT TSelector

Tags: c++, pointers, root-framework

I'm using the scientific framework ROOT, so I'll provide some specifics about what I'm doing with that, but if anyone has any general ideas about what could cause this perhaps I can go into the source code and figure out what is happening, since I know not a ton of people have used ROOT.

I'm processing a TTree (ROOT data structure) using T.Process(). Basically, T.Process uses a class called objdef to analyze the data in the TTree. It loops over data in the TTree and fills vectors which will be output as a new TTree (I could go into more specifics if asked, but I figure it's better to state my general question than try to explain the entire ROOT framework in this question).

Pointers to the output vectors are declared in the objdef class definition. For most of the samples I run on, the entire system works great. But for some samples, the pointers sometimes appear to be truncated (?), causing seg faults. Here is an example:

Some pointers declared in the objdef declaration are:

```
std::vector<double>   *ele_pt;
std::vector<float>   *ele_charge;
std::vector<double>   *ele_eta;
```

when I run T.Process(), the pointers come out to be, for example:

```
ele_pt: 0x2ec45a0                                                                                                                                                                                                 
ele_charge: 0x2ec5840                                                                                                                                                                                             
ele_eta: 0x2d89
```

What the heck is up with the third pointer! which pointer gets truncated seems to be random during each run of the code.

I wish I could be more specific, perhaps some pointed questions from SO could help me determine what's happening. Or, if anyone knows general things that could cause pointer truncation like this, I would love to hear it.

UPDATE

When I do sizeof on a bad pointer, it returns 8.

UPDATE 2

Evidently, some of the pointers were initialized to random values (or never initialized to zero?) before any memory was actually allocated, and then no memory was allocated to them. I suspect some bug deep in the ROOT framework (specifically Cint), but I've found a workaround - to just explicitly set all of the pointers to 0 and thus force ROOT to allocate them memory and give them a memory address. It is working now.
It appears that perhaps the pointers weren't actually truncated--instead, they were just a small value. They never had a real memory address so they couldn't have been truncated in the first place.

Comment: Do you call new properly? Do you pass those pointers to functions correctly? Do you have memory corruption between declaration and usage?

Comment: The pointers aren't really passed ever - they are data members of the objdef class, and when I check their values in the class they are bad. Perhaps there is memory corruption...

Comment: Do you call new on them?

Comment: This is an issue I am running into - I don't call new explicitly, ROOT does somewhere. I'm slogging through thousands of lines of ROOT source code to try to find where that actually happens :)

Comment: You could try tools like valgrind to help figure out the corruption

Comment: This is really hard to debug with the info you have given. The object holding the pointers is probably being corrupted. It is a stack object, or where is the storage for the object?

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod - I'm aware how hard it is to debug with this information. It is all the information I have at the moment :/

Comment: where in the code are the pointers declared? Are they in a class? Or just local variables? Static variables?

Comment: Ok I see you said in a class. Now what is the storage class of the object? Is it `new`'d or just local?